# Plot the mean and SD plot using two pandas series in python

Tags: python, pandas, line-plot

I have two pandas series: mean_Series and STD_series. length of each of these series is 160.

I want to plot a line chart of the mean_series and have a shaded region around it using the STD_series.

Data:

```
> mean_series        STD_series
>     1121.22                9.1121
>     1132.22                9.4663
>     1124.22                9.4405
>        .                      .
>        .                      .
>        .                      .
>     1522.25                12.5521
>     1562.25                12.7721
```

code I have used:

```
plt.plot(mean_series,label='mean', color='red')
plt.show()
```

I want to add shaded region around the mean line plot using STD_series.

Comment: Please include a sample of your data and the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [ax.fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html). See it in action:

```
x = [90,100,110]
mean_series = pd.Series([10,11,10.5],index=x)
STD_series = pd.Series([1,2,.5],index=x)
ax = mean_series.plot(ylim=(0,20))
lower_bound = mean_series - STD_series
upper_bound = mean_series + STD_series
ax.fill_between(x,lower_bound,upper_bound,alpha=.3)
```

[image: mean + shaded SD]

Comment: getting an error : "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: does my example code work for you as is @KathanVyas --it should? If it does, then the issue appears to be due to your data. Are both the `index` and `value` of your Series floating point numbers?

Comment: This worked. I need to covert all values either in float or int. thank you